Getting error in authorization "MsalInteractionRequiredException: AADSTS90083: Request is unsupported"
We have registered one Azure Function App and one corresponding client app in Microsoft Entra Id.
With grant_type ‘Authorization Code’ the authorization of the API is working fine, but for grant_type ‘Client Credentials’ we are getting below error:

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalInteractionRequiredException:
AADSTS90083: Request is unsupported. Trace ID:
20d89e47-3937-4535-b174-8cc57d31a400 Correlation ID:
c2bc0944-902d-4768-851e-615bcfd6776c Timestamp: 2024-04-09 06:09:57Z
at
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:89)
at
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:17)
at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
... 1 more Caused by:
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalInteractionRequiredException:
AADSTS90083: Request is unsupported. Trace ID:
20d89e47-3937-4535-b174-8cc57d31a400 Correlation ID:
c2bc0944-902d-4768-851e-615bcfd6776c Timestamp: 2024-04-09 06:09:57Z
at
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceExceptionFactory.fromHttpResponse(MsalServiceExceptionFactory.java:37)
at

We tried to change scope to different values. also added app roles.

Can you share your code in the question?

@DasariKamali please find below the code we used :

final IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret);
final ConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(clientId, credential)
.authority(authority).build();
IAuthenticationResult result;
try {
final OnBehalfOfParameters parameters = OnBehalfOfParameters
.builder(SCOPE, new UserAssertion(authToken)).build();
result = cca.acquireToken(parameters).join();
}
catch (final Exception ex) {
throw ex;
}

I successfully retrieved the access token using the code below with client credentials.
Code :
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Main {

    private static String clientId = "<clien_ID>";
    private static String clientSecret = "<client_secret>";
    private static String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>";
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            acquireToken();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void acquireToken() throws Exception {
        final IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret);
        final ConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(clientId, credential)
                .authority(authority)
                .build();

        final Set<String> scopes = Collections.singleton("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
        final ClientCredentialParameters parameters = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(scopes).build();

        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = cca.acquireToken(parameters);
        IAuthenticationResult result;
        try {
            result = future.get();
            System.out.println("Access Token: " + result.accessToken());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

Output :
The code above ran successfully, obtaining the access token with client credentials as shown below.

